# onClick is not working.And i want send 'cid' depend on the the result button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to send 'courseid' to local storage depend on the button clicked but onclick is not working.Is there a way to recieve the relavant 'courseid' to the onclick function based on the button clicked.

```
 handleClick(e) {
        let courseid = e;
        alert(courseid);
        localStorage.setItem("course", JSON.stringify(courseid));
     }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{marginTop: '6%', marginBottom: '25%'}}>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>


                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    {
                        this.state.data.map(function (course) {
                            return <tr>
                                <td key={course.id}>{course.cid}</td>
                                <td key={course.id}><Button type="button" style={{width: '75%'}}
                                                            onClick={this.handleClick(course.cid)}>View
                                    Course</Button></td>
                            </tr>;
                        }.bind(this))
                    }


                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing `this.handleClick` as a reference to a function but you actually invoke it. thus passing the returned value of this function (in this case `undefined`).

You can wrap it with another function and inside that function body invoke your handler:

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(course.cid)}
```

Note hat with this way it will create a new function reference for each render cycle and **MAY** or **MAY NOT** create a performance hit.